# Fetch data from complex SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below mentioned SQL table in Oracle

```
FILE_NAME)            ROW_NUMBER     COL_NAME      COL_VALUE  
----------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------
EnivData.properties    1            Host                 server1.com          
EnivData.properties    1            Port                 8081                 
EnivData.properties    1            Username             server1user          
EnivData.properties    2            Host                 win-serv2.com        
EnivData.properties    2            Port                 9900                 
EnivData.properties    2            Username             server2-user-john    
EnivData.properties    3            Host                 linux-server3.com    
EnivData.properties    3            Port                 7898                 
EnivData.properties    3            Username             server3-user-mike
```

Below mentioned query works fine

```
select col_value 
from testmytable  
where col_name='Port' and 
      row_number = (select row_number 
                    from TESTMYTABLE  
                    where col_name='Host' and Col_Value='server1.com')
```

Now, I need to fetch value of `COL_VALUE` for `Username` where `Host = server1.com and Port = 8081`

I am NOT able to place in correct where clause in SQL query which can give me correct result (`COL_VALUE` for `Username`).

Please help.

Comment: Can you also post the exact record which you want to see in your query output ?

Comment: Exact record is -   Username = server1user. I need to get "server1user" from above mentioned table where Host="server1.com" and Port=8081. Hope, I  have answered your question.

Comment: Aren't key/value tables a nuisance to work with? ;-) Is there a good reason why you don't simply have a table with three columns for host, port and user name? It would be so much better.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner what if there are a dozen other settings? The table would grow horizontally then.

Comment: @Salman A: Yes. What's wrong with that? I've seen tables with more than hundred attributes. It seems that in Abhay Agarwal's table all three attributes are mandatory, so it would be good to have a proper table with three non-nullable columns with appropriate data types and with an appropriate unique key instead of a key/value table.

Comment: Just to answer above question - if you notice mt first column is file name  ... my column names comes from file ... so ... one file can have  column names - host, port, username , second file can have column names - system, prefixURL, isDisabled ... so summary is that my column names are also dynamic

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following  query to get your the output. But if you are sure there is always going to be 3 entries per row number there may be better solutions than this.

```
select * 
  from (
select col_name,col_value 
  from testmytable 
 where  row_number in (select row_number 
                         from TESTMYTABLE  
                        where col_name='Host' 
                         and Col_Value='server1.com')
   and row_number in (select row_number 
                         from TESTMYTABLE  
                        where col_name='Port' 
                         and Col_Value='8081')
        )x
   where x.col_name in('Host','Port','Username')
```

Another solution would be to convert the rows to columns(ie have columns host_val,port_val,username_val) and filter the columns based on the value you wish to search on

Eg:

```
with data
  as (
        select row_number
              ,max(case when col_name='Host' then col_value end) as host_val
              ,max(case when col_name='Port' then col_value end) as port_val
              ,max(case when col_name='Username' then col_value end) as username_val
          from testmytable 
         group by row_number
     )
select username_val
  from data  
where host_val='server1.com'  
  and port_val=8085
```

Comment: Yes, I am sure that there are going to be exact 3 entries per row

Comment: thanks for your reply. Please let me know if there are better solution if we have exact 3 entries per row

Comment: One option would be to convert the rows to columns (ie have columns as host_val, port_val and username_val) and then filter them out. I have included an alternate solution

Answer (score 1):

Key/value tables are best accessed with aggregation. Here is how to find the user name(s) for host `'server1.com'` and port `'8081'`.

```
select max(case when col_name = 'Username' then col_value end)
from testmytable  
group by row_number
having max(case when col_name = 'Host' then col_value end) = 'server1.com'
   and max(case when col_name = 'Port' then col_value end) = '8081';
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I need combination of both - means where host = server1.com and port=8081 then what is the value of "username" .

Comment: I've added a typical key/value query to my answer that should get what you want.

Comment: I've removed my original answer. George Joseph has just updated his answer to show a similar query to mine. You may prefer his solution, as his `WITH` clause makes the query even more readable. Anyway, it seems you should rather change your table design so as to have a proper table with three columns for host, port and user name in the first place.

Comment: Yes, the key-value database design has problems when it comes to fetching data, very easy to insert data into one large table, but hard to write queries. Also worry about data integrity(constraints to be enforced would be very difficult. Eg: Enforcing that Port number should be unique,Foreign keys not possible, Date validation etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` the table with itself to pull related data together:

```
SELECT
    t1.COL_VALUE AS 'Host',
    t2.COL_VALUE AS 'Port',
    t3.COL_VALUE AS 'User'
FROM       t AS t1
INNER JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.ROW_NUMBER = t2.ROW_NUMBER AND t2.COL_NAME = 'Port'
INNER JOIN t AS t3 ON t1.ROW_NUMBER = t3.ROW_NUMBER AND t3.COL_NAME = 'Username'
WHERE t1.COL_NAME = 'Host' -- this is important
-- you now have the three values available inside t1.COL_VALUE, t2.COL_VALUE
-- and t3.COL_VALUE waiting to be filtered
AND   t1.COL_VALUE = 'server1.com'
AND   t2.COL_VALUE = '8081'
```

Alternately you can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT col_value
FROM t
WHERE col_name = 'username'
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t
    WHERE row_number = t.ROW_NUMBER AND col_name = 'host' AND col_value = 'server1.com'
)
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t
    WHERE row_number = t.ROW_NUMBER AND col_name = 'port' AND col_value = '8081'
)
```